# Hello guys , Can anyone tell me how to show custom call screen on lock screen when notification arrived on my app in android?

Tags: android

I am developing an android app in that i have implemented voip call functionality. I have made a custom call activity in my application like whatsapp .It works fine when my phone is unlocked. but when my phone is locked i cant see my call activity when notification arrive. Can i anyone tell me how to show my custom call activity while my device is locked and how to handle click listeners on my call activity after showing on lock screen on my phone? thanks in advance guys please help.

Comment: no one has answered of my question even on stackover flow.

Comment: Use a fullscreen notification with a fullscreen intent
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification#fullScreenIntent

Comment: See also: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telecom/InCallService#showing-the-incoming-call-notification

Comment: thanks but it did not work

Comment: can you tell what is ConnectionService Class for?can i achieve voip call functionality using ConnectionService class in android?

Comment: Yes, read the telecom documentation:

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telecom/package-summary

Comment: I have read about Connection service class and implemented too but I am not able to make call on internet. Can you give me some hints so that I can start properly to add internet calling using connection service class?

Comment: I've never built an VOIP app so can't help you there. Look at Google samples or maybe the AOSP dialer has some code to get you started.